# How to Use Localized Resources outside App's Bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, bundle, sandbox

I'm developing an iPad App with downloadable content to be able to persist it through updates.
I'm storing my content in Library/Caches dir seems to work fairly ok except for localized html content: when i was storing it in app's bundle i had $LANG_CODE.lproj folders and had no issues. Know that i migrated all those lproj folders in Caches dir, localized content won't load. Assuming that i could do the logic by myself of finding the current locale then branching through different paths to get proper content i was wondering if there was a better way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSBundle` and point it to a directory in you caches dir. As long as you have `.lproj` folders in that directory, you should be able to access localized resources in the same way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your super quick answer and correct support!